# Find top 3 most ordered product per supplier in mysql 8.x

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to find the top 3 most ordered products **per supplier** in mySql. Here's my simplified model and its tables (primary keys are in *italics*):

**Product** :
*product_id*,
name,
supplier_id

**Supplier** :
*supplier_id*, name

**Order_item** :
*order_item_id*, product_id

So 1 supplier can have N products, 1 order_item has 1 product.

So far this is what i was able to get :

```
SELECT count(*), p.name, s.name FROM order_item oi
JOIN product p on oi.product_id = p.product_id
JOIN supplier s on p.supplier_id = s.id
GROUP BY p.product_id, s.id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

But this gives me the 3 most ordered products among every supplier, not per supplier. In the exemple below, my sql request would give me this :

| Count | Product.name | Supplier.name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1450 | Strawberry | Good ol'farm |
| 1200 | Salmon | Fishing |
| 1150 | Shrimp | Fishing |

But I would like a result similar to this (N groups of top 3's):

| Count | Product.name | Supplier.name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1450 | Strawberry | Good ol'farm |
| 1000 | Orange | Good ol'farm |
| 350 | Lemon | Good ol'farm |
| 1200 | Salmon | Fishing |
| 950 | Carp | Fishing |
| 1150 | Shrimp | Fishing |

Thank you.

Comment: Mysql what version

Comment: Hi, that would be 5.7.33

Comment: It's about time I updated you, isn't it?

Comment: Please try reversing the GROUP BY statement: `GROUP BY s.id, p.product_id`. Hope I got your interest right.

Comment: That's a shame. I've ceased supporting < 8.0

Comment: @Johannes the order of a group by only has a bearing on a rollup

Comment: @JohannesWulf this gives me the same wrong result

Comment: @CaiusJard I could use a local version of MySql 8.x though, would that change anything ?

Comment: Yes, MySQL 8 has window functions support.

Comment: 'I could use a local version of MySql 8.x though' - but window function solution would not be backward compatible , if that's ok https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

Comment: that's okay, i just need a csv extract out of this sql request, there's no code involved in production behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 8 you should be able to:

```
WITH prodSupCounts AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by s.name ORDER BY count(*) DESC) rn, p.name, s.name, count(*) as ct 
  FROM 
    order_item oi
    JOIN product p on oi.product_id = p.product_id
    JOIN supplier s on p.supplier_id = s.id
  GROUP BY p.product_id, s.id
)
SELECT * FROM prodSupCounts WHERE rn <= 3
```

This should provide a column `rn` that is an incrementing counter from 1, in order of descending sale count, and the counter starts from 1 per supplier, so saying `rn<=3` gives 3 rows per supplier